# Flutter: How to parse an html text and separate bold, p, italic, etc tags to corresponding text widget

Tags: flutter, dart, html-parsing

The backend API provides me data text as

```
<p> hello <b> im bold and <i> im bold and italic </i> bold only continues.. </b> <p>
```

How can parse this in dart to normal text for applying some RichText widget over it?

Comment: Did you find any solution here?

Comment: Not really. But finally I had to use the package flutter_html which create an HTML kind of widget. There are limitations, but this is the closest one.